# Identify component C848

Tags: identification

This must be a diode, but which?

Does anyone have a clue?

I can't find anything with such a marking.

[image]

Comment: C8 or C84 is likely the part number, with the trailing digit(s) meaning something else.  Possibly similar to the [BV-SMCJ85CA](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2306061453_Bencent-BV-SMCJ28CA_C2929550.pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The markings match with a [Brightking SMBJ22A](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2304140030_Brightking-SMBJ22A-TR13_C309953.pdf) TVS diode. "LX" is the actual marking and seems to be damaged in your picture.

[image]

(Source: [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/TVS_Brightking-SMBJ22A-TR13_C309953.html))

[image]

Comment: Excellent. Thanks! 
The damage you suspect is a residue from conformal coating.